# Does Firebase's internet connection checking using (".info/connected") reference add to costs?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the (".info/connected") database reference to check the user's Internet connection. I have used the profiler tool to check the data download but it does not show any data download. So, does firebase add this to the users' download costs or any other costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no data round trip with the database to query `.info/connected`.  Its value is based only on whether or not the Firebase Realtime Database SDK has an open socket to the server.

Comment: So it does not add to the cost then?

Comment: There's no cost in terms of bandwidth, if that's what you're implying.  There is some computational cost in executing any code.

Comment: No, i mean would it be added to my bill of the firebase account?

Comment: Just listening to that location shouldn't incur any costs.  Whatever you do inside your listener might cost something.